# How to use readFragment method of cache in graphql?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

```
const newProduct = cache.readFragment({
    fragment: ProductFragment,
    id: `Product:${product._id}`,
});
```

where,

```
export const ProductFragment = gql`
  fragment ProductBody on Product {
    _id
    alias
    oldPrice
    price
    campaignPriceTemp
    category {
      _id
      alias
      description
      metaDescription
      name
      slug
      image
      position
      status
    }
    description
    ean
    name
    slug
    stock
    status
    shop {
      _id
      slug
      basicInfo {
        shopName
        logo
        bannar
      }
      flagship
      prime
      status
    }
    reviews {
      rating
    }
    allowedPaymentList
    deliveryCharge {
      _id
      name
      price
    }
    deliveryTime {
      _id
      name
    }
    thumnails {
      approvalStatus
      image
      color
    }
    metaKeyWords
    rewardPoint
    rewardPrice
    shortDescription
    sku
    variantOptions {
      _id
      displayName
      name
      values {
        displayName
        value
      }
    }
    variants {
      _id
      price
      oldPrice
      stock
      # variantOptions {
      #   optionId
      #   val
      # }
    }
  }
`;
```

giving Missing field __typename in product body {} and also all subfields section I'm using here. Previously I used a different product fragment and now I'm using new one because I'm using another data source from rest api.

I'm getting newProduct null. Why is this, I'm confused.
But If I use another product fragment with different fields, I get appropriate newProduct.

Comment: Can you also share the fragment which is working? There are chances that the fragment shared in question (which returns null) has certain fields which are not present in cache and therefore, apollo client is returning null.

Comment: I cut down some fields from old one, so how can it affects ? @Raeesaa

Comment: The only use-case where apollo client would return null for existing record in cache is, if there are additional fields in selection set which were not present in original query / cache. Quote from apollo client documentation - `Beginning with Apollo Client 3.3, readFragment always returns null to indicate insufficient data (missing ID or missing fields), instead of throwing a MissingFieldError.` I would suggest checking if all these fields specified in fragment are present in cache using apollo client developer tool or comparing with original query.

Comment: any alternative solution ? @Raeesaa

Comment: Matching fragment with that of original query is the only way around as far as I know.